# FineUploader : add upload buttons in template markup

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

With the fineUploader jQuery plugin, I am trying to add several upload buttons in my fineUploader template.

But it seems that the `extraButtons` option does not look for elements inside the template, only inside the DOM, before the template is being added to the DOM.

http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/extra-buttons.html

So if the extraButtons elements are inside the template, fineUploader does not find them.

I don't want to add my buttons outside my template ... Can fineUploader target extraButtons inside a template ?

My fineUploader instanciation looks like this :

```
$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        debug : true,
        extraButtons: [
            {element: $('#upload-pictures-btn1')},
            {element: $('#upload-pictures-btn2')},
            {element: $('#upload-pictures-btn3')}
        ],
        request: {
            endpoint: '/publish/upload'
        }
    });
```

And my fineUploader template looks like this :

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
        Add file
    </div>

    <div class="upload-pictures-btns">
        <div id="upload-pictures-btn1"></div>
        <div id="upload-pictures-btn2"></div>
        <div id="upload-pictures-btn3"></div>
    </div>

    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Uploading ...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
        <li>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>

            <span class="qq-upload-thumb">
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="365" qq-server-scale>
            </span>

            <span class="qq-upload-info">
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
            </span>

            <span class="qq-btns-wrapper">
                <button type="button" class="btn qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Annuler</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Re-essayer</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Supprimer</button>
            </span>

            <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

JS error at instanciation : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

If I move the 3 extra buttons out of the template, and put them directly in my HTML markup, it works. But I need them to be IN the template.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Code details and JS error added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is with your code. You are selecting elements from the DOM before Fine Uploader has even initialized. Of course these elements do not yet exist before an instance of Fine Uploader is created, since you have defined them in your template.

Currently, you *must* pass an `Element` to Fine Uploader when setting up your `extraButton` options, but there is [an open proposal to make this a bit more flexible](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1403). In the meantime one possible workaround involves creating your own `<input type="file">` and then [submitting it to Fine Uploader via the API](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles) once a user selects one or more files. For example:

```
<input type="file" name="extraButton">
<script>
document.querySelector('input[name="extraButton"]').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
   uploader.addFiles(event.target);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I know that fineUploader can't find the elements because the template has not been added to the DOM yet. But how can I "pass the id of each element and allow Fine Uploader to select them for me" ? Is this a feature of fineUploader ? Thanx.

Comment: Instead of supplying a jquery object for each extra button option, provide the id of each button.

Comment: I tried with both `{element: "upload-pictures-btn1"}` and `{element: "#upload-pictures-btn1"}`  but then I have this error : `Uncaught Error: [Fine Uploader 5.3.2] Can't apply style to node as it is not on the HTMLElement prototype chain!`

Comment: Sounds like an issue elsewhere in your code. Dev tools will likely give you a good indication as to where the issue lies.

Comment: Are you sure we can pass a string representing an ID to the `element` property of an extraButton ? I think we can't because the `css` function (line 87 of the uncompressed jQuery version) expects this value to be an HTML element. The `css` function checks if there is a `style` property on it, and of course, if this is a simple string, it has no `style` property, hence the error returned.

Comment: Ah yes, you appear to be correct. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time! It would still be great to have a cleaner solution with an API method or option.

Comment: Please do make your wishes known in the GitHub case I mentioned.